# Custom field in catalog product image gallery

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to add custom input field in `catalog product gallery` in magento 2.1.7

[image]

I already create a column in `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` table and also made related configuration for that field but it didnt work.

I also tried editing core files but that also didnt work.

How to do that?

Comment: have u did it ?

Comment: using custom module

Comment: Would you like to give me a tip how can i do that? Should I add column in media gallery table?

Comment: Give me you email i send you solution...

Comment: check your mail list...